# Codeigniter - I am looking to use/connect to a different database for one of my controllers and one model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am looking to use/connect to a different database for one of my controllers and one model. I posted this hear since on the forums of CI I am getting no response.

I added this in database.php:

```
$db['tdb']['hostname'] = "localhost";//localhost

$db['tdb']['username'] = "username";//root

$db['tdb']['password'] = "password";//empty

$db['tdb']['database'] = "databasename";

$db['tdb']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";

$db['tdb']['dbprefix'] = "";

$db['tdb']['pconnect'] = FALSE;

$db['tdb']['db_debug'] = FALSE;

$db['tdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;

$db['tdb']['cachedir'] = "";

$db['tdb']['char_set'] = "utf8";

$db['tdb']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

This as my model:

```
<?php

class Tadmin_model extends Model{

    function Tadmin_model(){

        parent::Model();

        $tdb = $this->load->database('tdb', TRUE);            
    }

    function FInsert($usernames){

        $query = $tdb->query("SELECT * FROM following");

        return $query->row();
    }    
}

?>
```

And this is the start of my controller:

```
<?php

class Tadmin extends Controller{

    function Tradmin(){

        parent::Controller();

        $this->load->model('tadmin_model');
```

And I get this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: tdb
>
> Filename: models/tadmin_model.php
>
> Line Number: ...
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   query() on a non-object in
>   /blablabla/tadmin_model.php on line
>   ...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

Your issue here isn't with the use of CodeIgniter's database functions, but with variable scoping in classes.  When you load your model you're connecting to the database and assigning the result to a local variable in the model's constructor.  When any function finishes, the local variables are discarded.  Later you try to call the query() method on the $tdb variable which has already been thrown away and get an error.

You need to store the results of $this->load->database() in a location which is available to both the constructor and the method.  You could move the $this->load->database() call into the controller method and connect to the other database every time you call the Tradmin method on your model.

The other way if you wanted to make $tdb available to all methods in the model is to use a member variable on the class, which would look like this....

```
<?php

class Tadmin_model extends Model{
    var $tdb;

    function Tadmin_model(){

        parent::Model();

        $this->tdb = $this->load->database('tdb', TRUE);            
    }

    function FInsert($usernames){

        $query = $this->tdb->query("SELECT * FROM following");

        return $query->row();
    }    
}

?>
```

Hope that helps.

Jim.

Comment: jim, i still got the error "Call to a member function query() on a non-object", even thought I have make the variable out of the constructor sope. please help.

Comment: sorry i've found the problem, I do not include second parameter which is 'TRUE' when loading the database. thanks pal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading $tdb inside the FInsert function?  Looks like $tdb may be a local variable and not accessible by FInsert...

Answer (score 0):

tdb needs to be defined outside of scope of constructor i.e. as class member like:

```
class Tadmin_model extends Model {
    var $tdb;

    function Tadmin_model() {
        parent::Model();
        $this->tdb = $this->load->database('tdb', TRUE);            
    }
}
```