# CodeIgniter - Call to a member function select() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm quite new to CodeIgniter. This is my code:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    function validate_user() {

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $validate_user = $this->db->get();

        if($validate_user->num_rows == 1) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm, receiving this error in my model file:

```
Call to a member function select() on a non-object
```

Currently I'm using CodeIgniter version 2.1.0. Please help me!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter - I am looking to use/connect to a different database for one of my controllers and one model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312511/codeigniter-i-am-looking-to-use-connect-to-a-different-database-for-one-of-my)

Comment: This is a very helpful thread that shows up high in the search results when searching this particular error. Please stop being so quick to cry duplicate.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think that you have to load the "database" library. The first way is to include the "database" in your application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

or in your class constructor:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model { 

     public function __construct() 
     {
           parent::__construct(); 
           $this->load->database();
     }
}
```

You can get more information here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your not sticking to the MVC pattern. You should be passing the data from view -> controller -> model.

As for sending information to the database, I'm pretty sure that CI handles xss and filter input, but you can never be to sure.

Also make sure you are loading your models in the config/autoload.php file or initiate the model  in the controller __construct() function

```
<?php
    class User extends CI_Controller
    {
        public __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('User_model');
        }
    }
```

or

```
$autoload['model'] = array('User_model');
```

So for example in my login view, I would have the CI create the fields needed.

```
<?php 
    echo form_open('admin');
    echo form_label('Username:', 'username');
    echo form_input('username', 'name');
    echo form_label('Password:', 'password');
    echo form_password('password');
    echo form_submit('submit', 'Login', 'id="loginBtn"'); ?>
    echo form_close(); 
?>
```

Now in the controller

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->model('User_model');
        $result = $this
                    ->user_model
                    ->index(
                        $this->input->post('username'),
                        $this->input->post('password'));
    }

}
?>
```

And the model

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model
{


    function index($username, $password)
    {
        $q = $this
                ->db
                ->where('username', $username)
                ->where('password', md5($password))
                ->limit(1)
                ->get('user');

        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->row();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To update my answer, you should probably use sha256, and salt + password hashing, since md5 is not considered best practices anymore

Answer (score 0):

`num_rows` is a function, thus you need to add `()`

```
if($validate_user->num_rows() == 1) {
        return TRUE;
}
```

Also, are you calling the parent class constructor in the constructor

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, it seems the db object is not initialized. Are you calling the parent class constructor in the constructor?

Comment: No. I'm not calling any constructor on my code. Even if I put the __construct() function, the error is still there saying that "Fatal error: Call to a member function where() on a non-object in C:\AppServ\www\ci\application\models\user_model.php on line 14"

Comment: Problem solved! I just add word 'database' in autoload.php file.
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');

Comment: just to make things clear, the parent constructor will ALWAYS be called unless you override the __construct() function in your child-class. In this case you need to explicitly call the parent's constructor, with parent::__construct();