# Fatal error: Call to a member function where() on a non-object codeigniter $query->num_rows()==1)

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter - Call to a member function select() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322124/codeigniter-call-to-a-member-function-select-on-a-non-object)

I'm newbie with codeigniter and have some problems.

**Error Message:** **Fatal error: Call to a member function where() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\moi\CI\application\models\model_users.php on line 12**

My Model:

```
class Model_users extends CI_Model {

 function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function can_log_in() {


    $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
    $this->db->where('pass', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows()==1) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

My Controller:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->login();
}

//Auslagern der Funktionen
public function login() {
    $this->load->view('login');
}

public function login_validation() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|valid_email|xss_clean|callback_username_check');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required|md5');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        redirect('main/members');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}

public function username_check() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('model_users');
    if ($this->model_users->can_log_in()) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'incorect User or Passwort.');
        return FALSE;
    }
}

}
```

please for help

Comment: Apprently the method `where` was called on something that is not an object. Can you show user the user superclass?

Comment: but is defined in my config file

Comment: I do not know code igniter, but the error is clear. `$this->db` is not an object. You are doing something wrong, if you think if you request the db field from the object's superclass.

Comment: how I can manage this problem?

Comment: Try to change the line `$this->load->model('model_users');
` in `username_check()` to `$this->load->model('model_users', '', TRUE);` to autoconnect to your database

Comment: Seems like you turned off database debugging. Could you please add you database.php configuration file (without the password ofc).

Comment: `$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] ='localhost';
$db['default']['username'] ='test';
$db['default']['password'] ='test';
$db['default']['database'] ='ci2';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] ='mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;`

Comment: Seems like something else is wrong - it should work. And if something was wrong, you should be notified whenever you load the database.

Comment: I've no idea why it does not work

Comment: Well, you need to start some debugging - try var_dump() on $this->db on strategic places and see what you get.

Comment: did you autoload the database?

Answer (score 1):

`$this->db` seems not to be defined. Seems you dont have a property names `$db` within your Model.

Have you used: `$this->load->database();` to initialize your database?

Try the following code:

```
class Model_users extends CI_Model {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
```

Information
Example: http://maestric.com/doc/php/codeigniter_models
User Guide: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/database/examples.html

Comment: ok I've added the $this->load->database(); in to constructor but now is the error on line 7.

Comment: Can you update your file in your current state (which line is line nr 7?)

Comment: the line 7 is exactly  $this->load->database();

Comment: `<?php

class Model_users extends CI_Model {

     function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }`

Comment: Have you set `$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);`?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function database() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\moi\CI\application\models\model_users.php on line 7

Comment: yes the database is autoloaded.$autoload['libraries'] = array('database'); -->application/config/autoload.php

Answer (score 1):

**See below URL**

[CodeIgniter - Call to a member function select() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322124/codeigniter-call-to-a-member-function-select-on-a-non-object)

**Try it**

```
class User_model extends CI_Model { 

     public function __construct() 
     {
           parent::__construct(); 
           $this->load->database();
     }

     public function can_log_in() {


        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user');
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $validate_user = $this->db->get();

       if ($query->num_rows()==1) {
         return TRUE;
       } else {
         return FALSE;
      }


}

}
```

Comment: `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');` -->application/config/autoload.php

Comment: i have update my answer please take a look.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function database() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\moi\CI\application\models\model_users.php on line 7

Comment: without // $this->load->database(); i got this Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\moi\CI\application\models\model_users.php on line 13

Comment: see this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322124/codeigniter-call-to-a-member-function-select-on-a-non-object

Comment: **Problem solved! I just add word 'database' in autoload.php file. $autoload['libraries'] = array('database');** but on my server is the database autoloaded

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your database on autoload? If not, you probably need to add this code to the constructor:

```
$this->load->database();
```

Comment: I got similar error message : Fatal error: Call to a member function database() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\moi\CI\application\models\model_users.php on line 7

Comment: You didn't by chance move or rename the Codeigniter system folder did you? It really sounds like none of the CI core is loading right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is not that much related to Codeigniter in specific nor to the database.

It is first of all a standard PHP error, for the general info please see

- [PHP Error Reference: Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983)

In your cases - just forget Codeigniter for a moment - this means that `$this` does bot have any `->db` or `->load` member, lines of code that fail:

```
$this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('email'));
$this->load->database();
```

It's obvious that this needs further debugging. Why aren't those libraries loaded? Why isn't it even possible to load the database?

Well actually this requires further debugging. It makes no sense in my eyes that you ask in comments further on, the other users can only give as good answers as you provide good information in your question. But asking a question is always limited as well, sure.

Maybe first of all post the complete code of your model class. It might just be the model class itself already screws it. Something a fresh pair of eyes here is faster to spot.

But there is no guarantee for that, just a possibility. You can break that also in other places. These are hard to reach, so you best do that using a step-debugger like Xdebug in your development environment.