# Message: Call to a member function get_users() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

HI im using codeigniter and i'm very new to this. i doing a simple program that will show data from database. but i'm having errors! this is my code

Controller file
User.php

```
class User extends CI_Controller{

    public function show(){

    $result= $this->user_model->get_users();

        foreach($result as $object)
        {
            echo $object->id;
            }
        }



    }

?>
```

Model file
User_model.php

```
class User_model extends CI_Model {


    public function get_users(){

    $fetch= $this->db->get('User');
    return  $fetch->result();


        }

    }



?>
```

Comment: Which version of CI you use??

Comment: @Saty sir this version CodeIgniter-3.1.4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php); specifically [Fatal error: Call to a member function ... on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12769983#12769983)

Comment: You're calling a function on something that's not an object. I don't know CI but it looks like you haven't setup your model in your controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter - Call to a member function select() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322124/codeigniter-call-to-a-member-function-select-on-a-non-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to a member function where() on a non-object codeigniter $query->num_rows()==1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847242/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-where-on-a-non-object-codeigniter-quer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter - Call to a member function select() on a non-object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322124/codeigniter-call-to-a-member-function-select-on-a-non-object)

Comment: Where you load model file??

Comment: obviously $this->user_model seems not to be an object.
you have to load it inside that class

Comment: @JanHančič Sir my code is in front of you!! i'm trying to solve it but able to figure out the what is wrong!! that is why i asked for your help sir

Comment: @NeoMorina yes sir i wasn't loading it!! thankyou very much sir

Comment: @Saty i was missing that line!! thankyou fir helping sir!! really thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to load the **model** into your **controller**. The best way to load the **model** to write a **constructor** for **controller** and load all required **model** into it. Please find the code below :

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();              
    $this->load->model('User_model');
}
```

Just copy and paste the code into your controller file and check. Hope it will do the work for you.

Comment: o thankyou sir!! how could i missed that line!! thankyou very much