# CodeIgniter load multiple model in same controller

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter

These is the controller

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller{
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model("admin/post_model");
    $this->load->model("admin/comment_model");
}
    public function index(){
    $data['post_res'] = $this->post_model->getPost();
    $data['com_res']  = $this->post_model->getComments();
    }
 }
```

I cannot load 2 model in the same controller. It gives me an error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getComments() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\application\controllers\ram-admin\dashboard.php on line 13
```

How can I possibly load the models?

Thanks you so much in advance!

Comment: You CAN load two models in the same controller, I did it plenty of times. The issue is another

Comment: Damien Pirsy is right it is a common practice to load multiple models in a single controller you should check your model file or post the model code here.....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Codeigniter - I am looking to use/connect to a different database for one of my controllers and one model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312511/codeigniter-i-am-looking-to-use-connect-to-a-different-database-for-one-of-my) .. also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/727208

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm getting the same error. I thought it must be something else, but now I've narrowed it down to "I think" having multiple controllers. Hence, I am here.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct() {
      parent::__construct(); 

    $this->load->model("admin/post_model","post_model");
    $this->load->model("admin/comment_model","comment_model");
  }

public function index(){

    $data['post_res'] = $this->post_model->getPost();
    $data['com_res']  = $this->comment_model->getComments();
}
```

Comment: The second argument to the `model` method is only required if you want the loaded model to have a different name locally.  In your example you could have omitted the 2nd arguments altogether and achieved the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the model correctly extends the `CI_Model` for `comment_model` and `post_model`

**example**:

```
  class comment_model extends CI_Model{    

   }

  class post_model extends CI_Model{    

   }
```

Comment: This answers this question exactly !

Comment: I had this error and it was very difficult to spot. I created a Model and incorrectly extended `CI_Controller`. It worked fine weirdly, but not when I tried to load it with more models in the same controller.

Answer (score 2):

*getComments(*) is **comment_model**, not post_model..

You can name your models by passing a second parameter;

```
$this->load->model('admin/comment_model', 'comments');
$data['com_res'] = $this->comments->getComments();
```

Comment: if that was the case then the error would be call to undefined function getComments not that he mentioned

Answer (score 0):

This is weird

I just put this line of code

```
 $this->load->model("admin/comment_model","comment_model");
```

before this one

```
 $this->load->model("admin/page_model","page_model");
```

And it works fine now :)

Thank you for all the response!

Comment: That did not fix your problem.

Answer (score -1):

For multiple models, you can do this:

```
$models = array(
    'menu_model' => 'mmodel',
    'user_model' => 'umodel',
    'admin_model' => 'amodel',
);

foreach ($models as $file => $object_name)
{
    $this->load->model($file, $object_name);
}
```

But as mentioned, you can create file application/core/MY_Loader.php and write your own method for loading models. I think this might work (not tested):

```
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {

    function model($model, $name = '', $db_conn = FALSE)
    {
        if (is_array($model))
        {
            foreach ($model as $file => $object_name)
            {
                // Linear array was passed, be backwards compatible.
                // CI already allows loading models as arrays, but does
                // not accept the model name param, just the file name
                if ( ! is_string($file)) 
                {
                    $file = $object_name;
                    $object_name = NULL;
                }
                parent::model($file, $object_name);
            }
            return;
        }

        // Call the default method otherwise
        parent::model($model, $name, $db_conn);
    }
}
```

Usage with our variable from above:

```
$this->load->model($models);
```

You could also allow a separate DB connection to be passed in an array, but then you'd need to have a multidimensional array, and not the simple one we used. It's not too often you'll need to do that anyways.

Comment: That's great, but are you sure it's necessary to mess with the core just to call 2 models? I often call 2 or more models and never had issues

Comment: This is just an alternative method to use multiple models. Is your getComments() function in the comment_model?
If so then only change $data['com_res']  = $this->post_model->getComments(); to $data['com_res']  = $this->comment_model->getComments();
Dont need to do above

Comment: This is completely unnecessary and doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the model names in an array like above.

```
$this->load->model(array("admin/post_model", "admin/comment_model"));
```

Comment: Loading them in two different calls is fine