# Connect one controller and one model with other database using codeigneiter

Tags: codeigniter

By using codeigneiter, I want to connect one controller and one model with another database.

Is it possible?

I am following this post [Codeigniter - I am looking to use/connect to a different database for one of my controllers and one model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312511/codeigniter-i-am-looking-to-use-connect-to-a-different-database-for-one-of-my), but I'm not getting any result.

Comment: share your applied codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use CodeIgniter documentation for Connecting to Multiple Databases

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

Or try it [Codeigniter - multiple database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268853/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections)